# d3js graph plotting at incorrect coordinates

Tags: javascript, html, svg, d3.js

i was trying to draw simple d3js graph.I got through drawing the axis and even plotted the data but the data isn't  appearing where it is expected to be.

As per my json data below

```
var d1 = [{
        value1: "30",
        value2: "10"
    }];
```

i'm trying to plot a circle at `coordinates x axis 30 and y axis 10`but the circle on the graph appears some where else.

Here is the jsfiddle [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/PJbna/)

Here is my code

```
    var d1 = [{
            value1: "30",
            value2: "10"
        }];



function Update(){
   var circles = vis.selectAll("circle").data(d1)
    circles
        .enter()
            .insert("svg:circle")
                .attr("cx", function (d) { return d.value1; })
                .attr("cy", function (d) { return d.value2; })
                .style("fill", "red")
    circles
        .transition().duration(1000)
            .attr("cx", function (d) { return d.value1; })
            .attr("cy", function (d) { return d.value2; })
            .attr("r", function (d) { return 5; })

    circles.exit ()
        .transition().duration(1000)
            .attr("r", 0)
                .remove ();


}



/*************************************************/


/*******************Real Stuff starts here*******************/

var vis = d3.select("#visualisation"),
  WIDTH = 600,
  HEIGHT = 400,
  MARGINS = {
    top: 20,
    right: 20,
    bottom: 20,
    left: 50
  },
  xRange = d3.scale.linear().range([MARGINS.left, WIDTH - MARGINS.right]).domain([0,100]),
  yRange = d3.scale.linear().range([HEIGHT - MARGINS.top, MARGINS.bottom]).domain([0,300]),


  xAxis = d3.svg.axis() // generate an axis
       .scale(xRange) // set the range of the axis
       .tickSize(5) // height of the ticks
       .tickSubdivide(true), // display ticks between text labels
  yAxis = d3.svg.axis() // generate an axis
       .scale(yRange) // set the range of the axis
       .tickSize(5) // width of the ticks
       .orient("left") // have the text labels on the left hand side
       .tickSubdivide(true); // display ticks between text labels 

function init() {
  vis.append("svg:g") // add a container for the axis
  .attr("class", "x axis") // add some classes so we can style it
  .attr("transform", "translate(0," + (HEIGHT - MARGINS.bottom) + ")") // move it into position
  .call(xAxis); // finally, add the axis to the visualisation

  vis.append("svg:g")
    .attr("class", "y axis")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + (MARGINS.left) + ",0)")
    .call(yAxis);
}
init();





$('#btn').click(function(){
    Update();
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works if you

- define the numbers as numbers and not as strings (i.e. `value1: 30` instead of `value1: "30"`) and
- use the scales you define (i.e. `return xRange(d.value1)` instead of `return d.value1`).

Working jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/PJbna/1/).

Answer (score 1):

Your circle is appearing at pixel (30,10), but that doesn't correspond to the place 30,10 as labeled by your axes. Use your scales to set the point's location.

```
            .attr("cx", function (d) { return xRange(d.value1); })
            .attr("cy", function (d) { return yRange(d.value2); })
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to apply `xScale` and `yScale` to your coordinates to transform them into the plotting space.

See [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PJbna/2/)

```
.attr("cx", function (d) { return xRange(d.value1); })
.attr("cy", function (d) { return yRange(d.value2); })
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually it is working fine.  It is just that top left corner is (0,0) and not bottom left (as I suspect, you must be assuming).

Set both x,y to 0. Circle will appear at top left corner.